# Rstudio on server abnormally terminates when loading large file into workspace

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm running Rstudio on an EC2 instance

- t1.micro
- Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-40-virtual x86_64)

and I am experiencing problems when trying to load an *.RData* file into the workspace. The file is 250MB in size and was created on my local machine (Mac OS Mavericks, RStudio v 0.97.551).

I uploaded the file via FTP and then tried to load it into the workspace. After some minutes I get:
 `"The previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash. You may have lost workspace data as a result of this crash".` Uploaded smaller files (e.g. 1 MB) works fine.

Maybe I should mention that I have one R script running in the background (I started it from the terminal window) on this EC2 instance. But I'm not sure if that's the problem, given that smaller files can be uploaded.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/)."

Comment: Check memory usage. Since micro instance has 613 MB RAM it is probably mot enough to run the system, Rstudio and load the data.

Comment: Is Rstudio not a tool used primarily for programming? I'm just wondering, maybe there is some kind of file size limit..I'm sure, I'm not the only one trying to run R scripts on larger data files on a server.

Comment: maybe ask on the RStudio forums?  R shouldn't crash if you try to load in a too-large file, it should just give an error.

Comment: thanks, I'll do. fyi: memory usage went up to 68% but quickly went down to around 20% although the loading process is not finished yet

Comment: @SPi I don't say there is something wrong with running R on server but micro instance is not a very good choice (apart from the fact it can be free) for data analysis. Although I am not Rstudio user I've just loaded 2GB data set and everything works fine. Just remember that 250MB on disk means substantially more when you load the data into RAM. Have you tried loading data from rsession? Does it work?

Comment: @zero323 you mean https://code.google.com/p/rsession/ ? I didn't try this so far, as I hoped to keep things simple by accessing RStudio via the browser. I guess I have to get a bigger Instance..even loading 60MB fails which is kinda weird.

Comment: No, plain old R terminal. You may try to create local virtual machine with similar configuration and check it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As zero323 pointed out, it was a memory issue. 
A medium EC2 instance did the job!